# Android: How to make notification visible even after app is cleared from memory

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to make a notification which cannot be cancelled by the user manually, just like google navigation notification. I don't know how to do it. 
Please Help.

**Below is my code that I had tried.**

```
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .setOngoing(true)
       .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
       .setContent(mRemoteViews)
       .setPriority(0) 
       .setTicker(ticker);
```

Thanks.

Comment: **.setOngoing(true)** I have already try it. so after any other Solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this

```
mBuilder.setOngoing(true)
```

Other option is to use intentService or background service to make your notification for you instead of the application context.